# How to change mysql database to h2 in JUnit integration test with Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I'm writing a `@SpringBootTest` to integration test my whole application. I only want to swap my multi-datasource configuration (`MYSQL`) by an embedded `H2` test database. All other application classes should be loaded as normal.

Problem: I'm using `DataSourceBuilder` to initialize the db as `apache tomcat` db pool by default.

And during test, though changing the `spring.datasource.*` properties to `h2`, I'm still getting the `mysql` connection. But why?

```
@Configuration
public class MultiDatasourceConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.multi1")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource ds, JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(ds)
                .persistenceUnit("multi1")
                .properties(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(ds))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.multi2")
    public DataSource multi2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean multi2Emf(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("multi2DataSource") DataSource ds, JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(ds)
                .persistenceUnit("multi2")
                .properties(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(ds))
                .build();
    }
}
```

application-test.properties:

```
spring.datasource.multi1.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.multi1.url=jdbc:h2:mem:ypsilon;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.multi1.username=sa
spring.datasource.multi1.password=sa
//multi2 accordingly
```

Testcase:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.ANY, connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public class MyTest {
}
```

Result:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'multi2' defined in class path resource
>   []: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: multi2]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   multi2] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is strange, because during debugging inside `emf()` I can see that the `DataSource ds` is correctly initialized. Means it is a `H2` db with correct URL etc, just like I configured.

---

Update: found out that in production I'm running:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

But this will also create the table if it does not exist.

Strange that in the junit test I had to change the property as follows:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

Comment: do you have h2 dependency in your pom?

Comment: `com.h2database`

Comment: do you have an application.properties (or equivalent) that is overwriting  the values in application-test.properties ?

Try injecting an Environment into MultiDatasourceConfig, go into debug, look at the property sources on the environment and see if there is a higher priority property source that is trumping the test app properties.

Comment: Why do you have two datasources and two entity managers? Is one for test and the other one for production? It's complaining about the `multi2` datasource.

Comment: I have two because I have to connect to 2 different mysql servers.

Comment: @PaulNUK Only `AnnotationsPropertySource` is before my `application-test.properties`. And it serves ` spring.test.database.connection=H2`, so property order should be correct.

Comment: Also the `DataSource` injected into the `emf()` method is correctly a `H2` db.

Comment: I just found out that changing 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` from `=update` to `=create-drop` fixes the exception. But why? Because in production I can run "update", and if the table does not exist it will be created. Why doesn't that work with the embedded h2 test db?